# input string was not in correct format converting string to long in c#?

Tags: c#

Hi all  i am working on mvc4 i have some issue here i am getting values from form collection 
once i am getting that values i am storing in array like 'String[]'  from that iam movint those 
values to my data base table but i am getting always only one issue 'input string was not in correct format'
could any body help me plz

here My code Follows:'

```
string[] BundleItemID = form.GetValues("txtbundleid");

for (int i = 0; i < skuid.Length; i++)
{
    ProductBundleItem productbundleitem = new ProductBundleItem();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BundleItemID[i]))
    {
        productbundleitem.BundleItemId = Convert.ToInt64(BundleItemID[i]);
    }
}
```

when i am trying to move values from 'Convert.ToInt64(BundleItemID[i])' to  'BundleItemId' i am getting an error 
  'input string was not in correct format'
thanks in advance

Comment: May you print BundleItemID[i] value and see what it is?

Comment: Not really sure why you are iterating over `skuid` and accessing the element from `BundelItemID`, you should [put a break point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/sc65sadd.aspx) on the line and see what is the value you are getting in `BundleItemID[i]`

Comment: is `BundleItemID[i]` a string representation of a number?

Comment: What is this skuid.Length also what does "txtbundleid" look like this will help in answering your question..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added a debug MessageBox so you can find the error.

```
   string[] BundleItemID = form.GetValues("txtbundleid");

    for (int i = 0; i < skuid.Length; i++)
    {
        ProductBundleItem productbundleitem = new ProductBundleItem();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(BundleItemID[i]))
        {
            long val = 0;
            if (!long.TryParse(BundleItemID[i], out val))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} is not a valid Int64 value", BundleItemID[i]));
                break;
            }
            productbundleitem.BundleItemId = val;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use long.TryParse to check if conversion is possible, like this:

```
long val;
if (long.TryParse(BundleItemID[i], out val)
    productbundleitem.BundleItemId = val;
else
    // handle situation when BundleItemID[i] is not a number somehow
```

Comment: Just in case, because a property, indexer or dynamic member access may not be passed as an out or ref parameter (as I do not know your implementation of the BundleItemId) and if there will be no success in the conversion your variable might become 0